# Restoring redirected sys.stdout and sys.stderr producing odd results

Tags: python, io-redirection

After looking through other stackoverflow posts, I can't seem to figure this redirection problem out. What I would like to do is suppress both `stdout` and `stderr`, and then restore them after the error is caught. The suppression works fine, but restoring them only half works.

If I try to suppress and restore `stderr` and `stdout`, the suppression works but not the restoring. If I only try to suppress/restore `stdout` it works (but then I get all the `stderr` text I don't want).

I can't reason out why there would be any difference causing `stderr` to block `stdout` from being restored, hoping for input on why that might be (or if I'm doing something weird/stupid)

Here's the code that I want to work but only suppresses out/err and doesn't restore (`'Restored stdout'` never prints):

```
sys.stdout = None
sys.stderr = None
try:
    op_args = op_parse.parse_args(selection.split(' '))
except SystemExit:
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
    print("Restored stdout")
```

Here's the code that suppresses `stdout` AND restores it (at the cost of printing the pesky `stderr`):

```
sys.stdout = None
#sys.stderr = None
try:
    op_args = op_parse.parse_args(selection.split(' '))
except SystemExit:
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    #sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
    print("Restored stdout")
```

**Edit:** I figured out a workaround, but I'm still interested in why the above problem occurs. My workaround is to reassign `stdout`/`stderr` to `= open("/dev/null", "w")` which does produce the behavior I want. Again I still would like input on the original problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this a little more elegantly by creating a context manager:

```
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def nullout():
    save_stdout = sys.stdout
    save_stderr = sys.stderr
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = save_stdout
        sys.stderr = save_stderr

with nullout():
    op_args = op_parse.parse_args(selection.split(' '))
```

A nice thing about context managers is that the code after the `yield` will get executed regardless of whether an exception occurs or not.

The reason you can't just set `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`to `None` is probably because `None` doesn't have a `write()` or `close()` method and generally doesn't behave like an output stream.

Answer (score 0):

As a high level comment, this technique is error prone and usually means something else is going wrong.  For example - restoring in the `except` above (instead of in a `finally`) means you restore stdout and stderr **only** if you fail.

I suspect that your observed problem may be due to your `op_parse` invocation.  Consider the below code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

sys.stdout = None
sys.stderr = None
try:
    print('before', file=sys.stdout)
    print('before', file=sys.stderr)
    # sys.stderr.write('hi')
    assert False
except AssertionError:
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
    print("Restored stdout", file=sys.stdout)
```

When I run it, I see: `Restored stdout`.

If I uncomment the `sys.stderr.write` line, I see: `lost sys.stderr`.

A safer approach would be to use a context to redirect stdout/err to `/dev/null` or an `IOStream` during your operation - or better yet, find the validation function being used internally and call that directly instead of looking for a system exit on a high level function (is `op_parse == opt_parse`?)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I agree that the restoring needs to happen in the finally block, in this test program I was purposely giving it an error every time so I didn't bother. I discovered the "/dev/null" trick before seeing this, so I can confirm that your solution does  work. (also op_parse is not opt_parse it was just a bad variable name to stand for 'options parse')